# Install4j Error during ExtractZipFileAction in the installation but the exctraction works correctly

Tags: java, install4j

During the installation of our product using install4j, an the following error appears during the action ExtractZipFileAction in the installation.log file.

```
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.ExtractZipFileAction [ID 1125]: null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
...
```

However the installation is correctly done and all files are correctly ectracted from the zip file. Do you know what happen and if I need to to pay attention to this error?

Comment: I cannot find such logging statements, which version of install4j do you use?

Comment: I use the 6.1.2 version (build 6275)

Comment: Can you try if this happens with 6.1.4 as well?

Comment: Sorry for the delay,
I've tried with the 6.1.4 and the error in the installation.log is still here.

Comment: Is it the exact same message, or does it now say "set permissions: null"?